# Nativescript: How to overlay one StackLayout over another StackLayout

Tags: css, nativescript

I have a search suggestion component that is displayed under a TextField.  whenever text is entered into the TextField the search suggestion component displays a list of possible matches based on the current entered text...  I have more content under the TextField that gets pushed to the bottom whenever the Search suggestion gets populated with results.  Is there any way to overlay the search suggestions over the content underneath it instead of pushing the content down?  in HTML/css I would apply the position absolute and z-index css properties to the search suggestion component but this doesn't seem to be the case in Nativescript.  I see that Nativescript does support the z-index css property but just applying that doesn't seem to do anything.  It doesn't look like Nativescript supports the position property...  Any idea how I can make this work/what i'm missing?

Comment: you could do it with a gridlayout? overlay elements on the same cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple quick options. One is to use a grid as mentioned in the comments. Set the views on the same row/col. This is the same as stacking views on the z axis. Or an absolute layout and use the same positioning of the views within that layout.

Comment: thanks the AbsoluteLayout works however it renders everything on top of each other without any clear separation between the 2 z-indices...  I tried assigning a background-color of white to the instant search result part without success...  Any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: I'd have to see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: hi @Brad  would it be ok to reference you to an [a bit related problem of myne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678239/tapping-a-layout-actually-taps-behind-elements) ?